# Adding GIT Post Commit hook to JBoss BPM 6.4

Tags: git, jbpm, jboss6.x

Am trying to add a post commit hook on the JBoss BPM 6.4 to push my saved changes automatically. However when i try to run the `git` command, I got the command not found error:

```
hooks/post-commit: line 2: git: command not found
```

Had tried to find relevant documentation online but none shows up. I'm trying to follow the steps in the link [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_brms/6.2/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap-repository_hooks).

To add on, the environment is on Linux.

Anyone know what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up install another copy of git onto the server and it worked.